# piTest removed call to "forEach" SURVIVED

Tags: java, spring, java-8, testng, pitest

**TL;DR** I think mutation should be killed but it survived. I am looking for the reason why it's happening and how to fix these 2 things: (1) Timeout (2) mutation survived.

**Details** I have a `spring` web application and am testing using `testng`. I have extracted the relevant part of the code. Please excuse me if I have introduced any problem while extracting the code for this question. I have a passing test case which verifies that the callFunction is called 8 times. This is verified using `verify(a, atLeast(8)).called();` After seeing the piTest report it seems that if the `callFunction` is removed the function will still have `a.called();` 8 times ... which is unexpected.

I have checked by removing `callFunction` from the source and the test case does fail. See the section *Modified1* `Rat.java`.

Also I have checked by removing the `forEach` and the test case does fail. See *Modified2* `Rat.java`.

There is an even interesting thing that when I changed only the (formatting) location of the text in `Rat.java` like shown in *Modified3* `Rat.java` section the `piTest` report changed.

**Type.java**

```
package lab.rat;

public class Type {
}
```

**Action.java**

```
package lab.rat; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component public class Action { 
    public void called() {}
}
```

**Rat.java**

```
package lab.rat; 
import java.util.HashMap; 
import java.util.Map; 
import java.util.stream.IntStream; 
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component; 

@Component public class Rat { 
    @Autowired private Action a;

    public void testee() { 
        Map<Type, Integer> properties = new HashMap<>(); 
        IntStream 
            .range(0, 8) 
            .forEach(index -> properties.put(new Type(), index));

        properties 
            .entrySet() 
            .stream()
```

**NOTICE FOLLOWING LINE**

```
            .forEach(entry -> callFunction()); // removed call to lab/rat/Rat::callFunction ? TIMED_OUT 
                                               // removed call to java/util/stream/Stream::forEach ? SURVIVED 
     } 
     private void callFunction() {
         a.called(); 
     } 
}
```

**RatTest.java**

```
package lab.rat; 
import static org.mockito.Mockito.atLeast;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify; 
import org.mockito.InjectMocks; 
import org.mockito.Mock; 
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations; 
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod; 
import org.testng.annotations.Test; 
import lab.rat.config.SpringConfigurationForTest; 

public class RatTest extends SpringConfigurationForTest { 

    @InjectMocks Rat rat; 
    @Mock Action a; 

    @BeforeMethod public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); 
    } 

    @Test public void testTestee() { 
        rat.testee(); 
        verify(a, atLeast(8)).called(); 
    } 
}
```

**Modified1 Rat.java -- test fails**

```
.stream() 
.forEach(entry -> {});
```

**Modified2 Rat.java -- test fails**

```
.stream();
```

**Modified3 Rat.java -- one more mutation created**

```
.stream() 
.forEach( // removed call to java/util/stream/Stream::forEach ? SURVIVED 
          // removed call to lab/rat/Rat::callFunction ? TIMED_OUT

          entry -> callFunction() // replaced return of integer sized value with (x == 0 ? 1 : 0) ? KILLED 

);
```

Comment: This is a sort of a bug. If I create a project with the code from question it does not reproduce the issue. So piTest is reporting the issue because of some thing else, perhaps multi threading or perhaps wrong configuration. https://github.com/hcoles/pitest/issues/401

Answer (score 2):

Years later but no one seemed to mention that (Spring) @Component and (Mockito) @InjectMocks are mutually exclusive solutions. You have multiple generated subclasses of Rat in play so PIT is simply confused about what's going on. It probably mutated the wrong one.